# Neo4j - Relationship Expander deprecated, using Lowest Common Ancestor

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-theory, deprecated

I'm looking to use the lowest common ancestor method here: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.8.M03/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/ancestor/AncestorsUtil.java?av=f

I got it working with the RelationshipExpander but that class is deprecated in favor of PathExpander, however I don't see how to apply PathExpander in this case.

Example here: 
http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.8.M03/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/ancestor/AncestorTestCase.java?av=f

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AncestorUtil will be updated with PathExpander methods as well (probably for 1.9), so don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this. So far, I've seen that AncestorUtil has not changed.

From the following link:
http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/RelationshipExpander.html I would expect that it might be possible to use it somehow.

There was also a usage example before, that we can see here. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.neo4j/neo4j-graph-algo/1.9.4/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/ancestor/AncestorTestCase.java?av=f Anyone knows how this could be adapted?